# how to create frames animation in CSS where each frame is a different HTML element?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to create ASCII animation in CSS. I have this HTML (simple example with 3 dots):

```html
<div class="terminal-loader">
    <span>.</span>
    <span>..</span>
    <span>...</span>
</div>
```

And I want to animate appearing of those frames (spans) one by one. One span is one frame. And a single frame should appear at the time.

1. Frame `.`
2. Frame `..`
3. Frame `...`
4. Frame `.`
5. Frame `..`
6. Frame `...`

This is my attempt:

```css
body {
    background: black;
    --color: #ccc;
    color: var(--color);
    --size: 5;
}
.terminal-loader {
    color: var(--color);
    font-size: calc(var(--size, 1) * 14px);
    position: relative;
}
.terminal-loader span {
    color: var(--color);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: appear 1s infinite steps(3, start);
}
.terminal-loader span:eq(2) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.terminal-loader span:eq(3) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes appear {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="terminal-loader">
    <span>.</span>
    <span>..</span>
    <span>...</span>
</div>
```

I'm not exactly sure what should I do to make it a frame animation.

How to animate elements where each HTML element is a different animation frame? Is this possible with CSS alone?

Comment: https://css-loaders.com/dots/

Comment: @TemaniAfif this doesn't explain how to animate frames with different HTML elements only how to create dot loaders.

Comment: you frame contains dots so it's more likely you want to create a dot loader. If it's not the case, update with a better example to avoid getting answer involving only dot loaders

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't want to create dot loaders. I want frame animation with different text. I may want to change the animation to be 4 characters:`/` `|` `\ ` `-` there are lot more possible loaders that I want to test.

Comment: To be clear, you don't need interpolation between frames?

Comment: @Kaiido no, only frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack them vertically, make the container have the height of one element then use a translation

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.terminal-loader {
  --n: 3; /* number of frames */
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 1lh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.terminal-loader span {
  display: block; /* or use div elements */
  animation: appear 1s infinite steps(var(--n))
}

@keyframes appear {
  100% {
    translate: 0 calc(-100%*var(--n)); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="terminal-loader">
  <span>/</span>
  <span>*</span>
  <span>\</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks, is there a way to extract a number of frames into a CSS variable? This will make the solution universal. Is the 3 in the comments the number of frames?